# MergeAdapter and ViewPager

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

So I'm working on a scrolling layout that has a couple header lines (pictures and whatnot) and a ViewPager. I'm using MergeAdapter because I want to use the Sticky List Headers library to make the ViewPager indicator tabs, which would ideally end up being a list item technically, stick to the top when the user scrolls. I'm doing everything just like the demo but when I go to run my code I get the error in my logcat:

```
01-07 00:02:19.009: W/dalvikvm(12044): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e2d930)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044): java.lang.RuntimeException: You must override newView()!
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at com.commonsware.cwac.sacklist.SackOfViewsAdapter.newView(SackOfViewsAdapter.java:175)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at com.commonsware.cwac.sacklist.SackOfViewsAdapter.getView(SackOfViewsAdapter.java:147)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at com.commonsware.cwac.merge.MergeAdapter.getView(MergeAdapter.java:271)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.onLayout(CustomViewAbove.java:849)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:985)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)01-07          00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5191)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
01-07 00:02:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(12044):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have the jar files for MergeAdapter and the SackOfViewsAdapter so I can't figure out what's going on. I even get the same error if I comment out the ViewPager stuff.

Is there a way you have to structure your XML if you want to add XML elements via addView, addViews, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, either `MergeAdapter` thinks there are more things in the `SackOfViewsAdapter` than there actually are, or you have a `null` entry in the list of views that you handed to `MergeAdapter` `addViews()` (or a single `null` `View` you added via `addView()`. My money is on the `null` scenario.

You should be able to determine whether it is the `null` entry problem yourself, by examining what you are supplying as views to `MergeAdapter`.

If you cannot track down the problem, and if you can create a sample project the reproduces the error, [file an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge/issues) with a pointer to the source code for the sample, and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think it may be an issue with how I have my xml setup. Right now, it's just a single ListView with nothing inside of it. So I guess I would have to add elements to the ListView that would be inflated along with the layout. I'll give that a go and see if it works.

Comment: Adding elements like TextViews and RelativeLayouts to a ListView via xml doesn't make any sense. So I guess I would have to manually build the views programatically instead of getting them somehow from xml.

Comment: @Wenger: You can inflate layouts yourself with `LayoutInflater` to pass to `addView()` or `addViews()` on `MergeAdapter`. However, these have to be separate layout files, not widgets in the layout file that has the `ListView` and other stuff for your activity or fragment. Or, you can construct them directly in Java if you so choose.

Comment: I see. So I would be inflating a layout, but it's not set as the current content view or anything. That way I can still use its xml elements. I'll try that out. Building stuff in code sucks.